# when it is in mobile resolution, the carousel items go down

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

when it is in mobile resolution, the carousel items go down

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAH2G.png)bootstrap carousel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RotOL.png)

```
<div class="container">
          <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
            <div class="carousel-indicators">
              <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
              <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-inner">[enter image description here][1]
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="/img/banner 1.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="banner 1">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
                  <h5>Velocida</h5>
                  <p>Coleta e entrega rápida de encomendas.</p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Serviços</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="img/banner 2.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="banner 2">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
                  <h5>Segurança</h5>
                  <p>A logística ideal para levar seus pedidos com segurança.</p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Serviços</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" class="d-block w-100" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
      <h5>Velocida</h5>
      <p>Coleta e entrega rápida de encomendas.</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Serviços</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" class="d-block w-100" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
      <h5>Segurança</h5>
      <p>A logística ideal para levar seus pedidos com segurança.</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Serviços</button>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```